# Magento - Invalid callback Error Scheduler after upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, error, extensions, ce-1.9.3.0

Magento Version: 1.9.3.0
After the recent update, the scheduler cron produces this error:

```
Error while running "customer_flowpassword"
"customer_flowpassword" messages:
---EXCEPTION---
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid callback: Model for mage_customer/observer::deleteCustomerFlowPassword does not exist' in app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Helper/Data.php(298): Mage::throwException('Invalid callbac...')
#1 app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Job.php(143): Aoe_Scheduler_Helper_Data->getCallBack('mage_customer/o...')
#2 app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(192): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Job->getCallback()
#3 app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/controllers/Adminhtml/JobController.php(92): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->runNow(false)
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Aoe_Scheduler_Adminhtml_JobController->runNowAction()
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('runNow')
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NB: This is only a temporary workaround or entry point to further debugging/a clean solution since you're editing a core file.**

Translated from http://www.henryschorradt.de/information/magento/:

In file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml
```

replace this line

```
<model>mage_customer/observer::deleteCustomerFlowPassword</model>
```

with this one

```
<model>customer/observer::deleteCustomerFlowPassword</model>
```

Flush your Magento cache and try again.